# Make complex gradient backgrounds

Tags: wpf, gradient

I would like to make pure-xaml background that have been made with Photoshop. I can't find a way to do it. Is it even possible?

Here is one I would like to make:

http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/776650radient.png

I tried things with RadialGradientBrush but it's not even close of this.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please describe what is the specific problem. The gradient you are trying to build seems to be made out of several layers. There is a decoration (With gradient of its own) and a background gradient which seems to be a simple linear gradient with 3 stops. OR is it the entire thing?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to make a multi-layer gradient

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this picture as a background image

```
 <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Source.jpg"/>
    </Button.Background>
```

or if you want to have xaml code you can open Blend -> File -> Import -> Import Adobe Photoshop File. The latter way out does not always reflect exactly the same.

Comment: I don't want to use an image, I wanted to "draw" it with gradients. Kobi Hari gave me a hint to make it. Thank you anyway